# Having Issue Refreshing Random Pages

Tags: php, html

I found this **random page** script which is in **PHP** file. I'm a bit frustrated that it's hard to **refresh** the page when I click on **refresh** (**reload**) on the **browser**. Each **random page** has an article and some have two images but mostly one image. There is only **3** articles.

The issue is that it takes **2** or **3 clicks** in order to **refresh** the **page**. There's **No** button, it only refreshed the **page** when you click **'reload'** the **page** on the **browser** (**all browser**) or visit to the site. In order for it to work it does always take at least **2** or **3 clicks** to refreshed.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
$pagesArray = array("article1.php", "article2.php", "article3.php");
$randNum = rand(0, count($pagesArray)-1);
echo $pagesArray[$randNum];
?>
```

I also try modify the script to used **"shuffle"**

```
<?php
$pagesArray = array("article1.php", "article2.php", "article3.php");
shuffle($pagesArray);
echo $pagesArray[0];
?>
```

and also to used **"array_rand"**

```
<?php
$pagesArray = array("article1.php", "article2.php", "article3.php");
array_rand($pagesArray);
echo $pagesArray[0];
?>
```

Is there a way to make the code better? I just want the code to **refresh** the different **pages** rather clicking **2 or 3 times** for it to work. I appreciate any suggestion how to make it works correctly or any example would be appreciate for me to see the full picture!

Thanks

Comment: You've shown three ways of achieving something, but no real question or need.  What isn't working?  What's wrong with any of the above, considering they all ought to work?

Comment: Hi g.d Thanks for the reply! The issue mainly is that it's hard to refresh it takes 2 or 3 clicks in order to work. When I click on refreshed on the first example ($randNum), For the second example (shuffle), it does that too. But for the last example (array_rand), it doesn't work maybe I wrote it wrong

Comment: What happens when you click once and wait? Does it timeout or does it eventually return a result? A performance issue (what you're describing) is not likely to be caused by one of these implementations.

Comment: Could it be that `rand`  and `shuffle` is simply returning the same result two times in a row? Do you only have 3 items in the array you're testing?

Comment: array_rand doesn't randomize the passed array, but it returns an  array containing the random keys.

Comment: A lesson in actual randomness: if you have only 3 items, and you display a random one, there's a 33% chance the same will come up. If you don't want that, store visited pages in a session and remove those from the array of possible next pages.

Comment: @ Nathaniel, Thanks for the reply! When I click once and wait it still on the same page. When I click it 2 times then it works. Then is it the browser?

Comment: @ Paul, Thanks for the reply! I just have 3 articles, yes the returning is the same artcile twice.

Comment: @ Wrikken, Thanks for the reply! What do you mean store visited pages in a session and remove those from the array of possible next pages? Each article doesn't have an array within the array. I apologizes if I don't understand what you meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with PHP, but if you're asking which method of selecting a random element in your array is fastest, I would guess that is option 1. Generating a random integer takes constant time, and returning an element of an array by the array index should take constant time as well. I don't know how shuffle is implemented, but I'm pretty sure getting a random number would take less time than shuffling an array of elements. Whatever the case, there shouldn't be a noticeable difference to the user if you only have a few elements in your array.

As for why it takes 2 or 3 refreshes for it to "work", I'm guessing that is probably because you're just returning the same page multiple times. If you can get what page the user is currently on (or has visited), you can just remove the item from the array before picking one.

Comment: Hi Zhihao, Thanks for the reply and explanation! My array has 3 articles when I click it once it won't do anything. I have to click it twice or a third time in order for the random article to appear. I apologizes if I don't understand what you mean when you mention "If you can get what page the user is currently on (or has visited), you can just remove the item from the array before picking one." You mean I have to take 1 article out from the array?

Comment: Let me see if I understand you correctly. Do you have a page with a button, and if you select the button it shows a random new page (taken from the array)? When it shows a new article, is the button still there for the user to click? Also, does it *always* take at least two or three clicks for it to work? Does it ever work on the first try?

Comment: Hi Zhihao, There's no button, it only refreshed the page when you click reload the page on the browser or visit to the site. Yes it does always take at least 2 or 3 clicks to work

Comment: If you never get a different page on the first refresh, then it probably isn't an issue of picking a page to return (I would still recommend option 1 for this), but rather *how* you're returning the page. I would double-check to see if the statements in your question are actually being called, and then also check to see if you're returning it correctly. Any more than that and I'm not sure how much I can help you because I'm not very familiar with PHP, sorry.

Comment: If you have any more information about the issue, I would also recommend updating your question so that others can see it and maybe help you more.

Comment: Hi Zhihao, thanks for the explanation. I will update the question.